# How to link a shared library compiled on different system architecture?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded-linux, dynamic-linking, ansi-c

I tried to link a shared library "libQRCODE.so" made for a POS device (embedded Linux) with 32-bit arm Linux but on my 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 machine. and I am getting this error :

```
gcc main.c -L. -lQRCODE -o output
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libQRCODE.so when searching for -lQRCODE
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQRCODE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this?

Note: I'm using latest gcc and the whole system is ANSI C.

Answer (score 4):

> How to link a shared library compiled on different system architecture?

## this is not possible.

You should either *cross-compile* your library on your 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 machine (preferable solution) or install a native compiler on your POS device.

If your POS is running some MIPS hardware, consider using packages like `gcc-multilib-mips-linux-gnu`

If your POS is running some ARM hardware, consider using some ARM emulator (like [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/)) on your Linux desktop.

Alternatively, download the source code of [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/), and compile it as a cross-compiler.

See also the source code of the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) static source code analyzer. It has (inside) some examples of cross-compilation.

I recommend to pass both `-Wall -Wextra` to your `gcc` [cross-]compilation command.

Comment: It is not possible to cross-compile the library cuz I don't have access to the source or object code (fin-tech secured software). I just have this library and I need to make it work. actually the library works fine on the POS but it takes 7 mins to update the software that's why I am trying to run it on my machine.

Comment: Then discuss this with your client/boss/manager.

Comment: A solution would be to create a docker container from your target system and compile there. That's how we are doing this.